# How do I duplicate the lowercase letters from a text file in Linux using grep/sed/awk?

Tags: linux, sed

<sup>[Editor's note: This question originally used the term "small letters" to refer to lowercase letters.]</sup>

I need to duplicate the lowercase letters from a file using grep/sed/awk, but I have no idea how to do that. For example, given the input `John has an Audi`, I would like the output to be: `Joohhn hhaass aann Auuddi`.

I am new to Linux so if you can provide a litle help it would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "small letters"? Can you provide an example please?

Comment: for example if a have : John has an Audi, the result is : Joohhn hhaass aann Auuddi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to replace each lowercase letter with two of that same lowercase letter, try `sed 's/\([a-z]\)/\1\1/g'`. That will turn `Hello world!` into `Heelllloo wwoorrlldd!`

As Ed Morton points out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919409/how-do-i-duplicate-the-lowercase-letters-from-a-text-file-in-linux-using-grep-se/28919473?noredirect=1#comment46100172_28919473), for certain locales this will not work. `sed 's/\([[:lower:]]\)/\1\1/g'` should work across all locales.

Comment: @dd1714: For the benefit of both answerers and future readers: If an answer _solved_ your problem, please _accept it_ by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you found it at least _helpful_, please _up-vote_ it by clicking the up-arrow icon.

Comment: its probably fine for you but just be aware that in some locales that will duplicate most upper case letters too, you should be using `[[:lower:]]` instead of `[a-z]`.